# What is the difference between a unity plugin and a dll file?

Tags: sdk, unity-game-engine

i am new to Unity and i am try to understand plugins. I have got the difference between a managed plugin and a native plugin, but what is not very clear to me is:

what is the difference between a plugin and a dll? what should i expect to find in an sdk to make it usable in my unity project?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean DLL instead of ddl?

Comment: yes that's what i meant. thanks for letting me notice

Comment: Unity users tend to call plugin anything added to a project that is not shipped with the engine. Whether it is native android, ios or plain C# asset bought from the store. Though there is a plugin folder in Unity that is used to store precompiled code like jar or dll. So a dll would be C# precompiled code that is part of a plugin you added or bought. Misleading innit?

Comment: @Everts Looks like that should be an answer instead.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @Everts comment instead of just copying it into an answer, I'll go a little into details here

### What is a plugin?

It's a somewhat vague word for a third-party library that is somehow integrated with the rest of your game. It means that it neither is officialy supported by Unity, nor is it a part of your core code. It can be "plugged" in or out without altering its internals, so it must provide some kind of API that can be used by the game code.

For example, you'll find many plugins that handle external services like ads, notifications, analytics etc. You'll also find a couple of developer-tools that can also be called plugins, like tile-based map editors and such.

Plugins come in many forms - DLL files are one example but some plugins actually provide full source code for easier use. And of course, other plugins will provide native code for different platforms, like Objective-C for iOS or .jars for Android.

So to answer your first question:

- DLL is simply a pre-compiled source file that can be a part of a plugin
- A plugin is a whole library that can consist of multiple files with different formats (.cs, .dll, .jar, .m etc)

### What do you need to use an sdk?

First of all - documentation. Like I said before, and like you noticed yourself, not all plugins give you access to the source code. And unfortunately, not many sdks have extensive and developer-friendly documentations so it can be a tough task to actually understand how to use a given sdk.

Secondly - the code. Many sdks give you some kind of "drag & drop" library, a single folder with all the neccessary files inside that you simply add to your Unity projects. I've also seen sdks that use Unity packages that you have to import via Assets > Import Package > Custom Package.

Once you have the code and documentation it's time to integrate it with your game. I strongly recommend using an abstract lyer in your game as, in my experience, you often have to change sdks for various reasons and you don't want to rewrite your game logic every time. So I suggest encapsulating sdk-related code in a single class so that you have to change only one class in your code when switching from, say, one ad provider to another (and keep the old class in case you need to switch back).

So you basically need three things:

1. Documentation (either a readme file or an online documentation)
2. The code (precompiled or source)
3. A versatile integration